# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled; "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" in C# wh

Tags: c#-4.0

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConnectingToMS_Access1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        OleDbDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Record", "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.oledb.12.0;data source='D:\\mydb.accdb'");
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            dr[0] = "abc"; 
            dr[1] = "def";
            dr[2] = "ghi";
            dr[3] = "jkl";
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
             da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);

             MessageBox.Show("Saved in Database");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this `INSERT` statement that the error refers to? It is nowhere to be seen in the code.

Comment: Also - simply posting a code file doesn't make this a question. Yes, you posted an exception as the title, but you really have not asked a question. As a reader I _assume_ you mean to ask how to correct the exception, but perhaps I am guessing wrong. Please ask an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly define the named columns in your query.

The problem is that you can't update columns based on column position. It might have been reasonable to expect that calling the Fill method would return both records and column-names, but it probably won't. After all, running that select query will return only data, not schema.